# Strange artifacts on rendering hard surface modeling

Tags: rendering

I am having quite a strange problem with the way my model renders. After modeling one of the objects of my scene, I created a quick light/camera setup to check the result of some hard surface modelling. When I set the 3D window to Render View, I get the object with what appears to be a scratches texture

[image: a detailed shot of the "scratches"]

the problem is that the object doesn't have any material applied; I have literally only done the modeling; when I apply some material to the surfaces, the material gets applied but underneath I can clearly see the "scratches".

[image: scratches under the anisotropic shader]

I have tried to append the geometry into a brand new file, and the problem appears to be bound to the geometry itself; the geometry is not perfect (it is mostly quads) but I don't think the problem is related to topology, for it happens with any object in the scene (including a satellite dish model with perfect topology). An interesting clue is that the actual render appears to be totally clean of any artifact.

I know this problem is not a deal breaker (specially since it doesn't seem to show in the final render), but I really would like to know what the solution to this quaint problem is.

Blend file available on request.

Can anybody help?

Thanks in advance.

Sept

Comment: When I move the geometry in object mode, nothing changes and there are no extra objects in the outliner; however, what you say about accidentally duplicating in edit mode makes sense; I am not sure how I would go about verifying that ...  but I notice that if I create a plane in a new layer (of the same file) and I subdivide it a number of times, the problem start happening. The more I investigate it, the less sense I can make of it.

Comment: Oh sorry; I have already removed all the doubles, at the minimum distance, before the first 3D window render; it appears there are no doubles left. And the fact that the actual render shows no artifacts, is really confusing (I thought the preview render and the render command were the same).

Comment: I found the solution; it was simply that I was viewing the viewport render in orthographic mode and it is a known issue that this mode will produce scratch-like artifacts. I can reproduce the issue and correct it consistently. Thank you guys for all your help.